# How can I prevent a QTextArea from being erased?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a QPlainTextEdit in a modal dialog window (subclass of QDialog).  Whenever I minimize the dialog and bring it back up, all the text in the QTextArea has disappeared.

How can I preserve the text in my QPlainTextEdit widget?

I've tried saving the text in the textedit widget like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.text_area = self.QPlainTextEdit()
    self.previous_text = ''

def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.previous_text = self.text_area.toPlainText()

def showEvent(self, event):
    self.text_area.setPlainText(self.previous_text)
```

But this approach didn't yield any appreciable results.

**EDIT:**
I've noticed that this only happens when I can actually hide the modal dialog ... which seems to only be possible when I use Xmonad as my window manager ... whenever I try this in GNOME or on Windows, this behavior cannot be reproduced because those window managers actually prevent the modal dialog from being minimized.

**EDIT:**
Following @Avaris's comment below, I tried enabling minimization for the modal `QDialog` like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

With this flag set, the vanishing text behavior can be replicated on Windows, GNOME and XMonad.

Here is a visual example from my Windows machine before I minimize the window:
[image: Before I minimize the window]

And here's what it looks like after I bring up the window again:
[image: After I minimize the window]

**EDIT:**
Text is written to the modal dialog's `QPlainTextEdit` like so:

```
def write(self, text):
    self.text_area.insertPlainText(QtCore.QString(text))
```

The text itself is retrieved as a python string from a system of threads whose standard out has been captured and redirected.  By the time is gets to the above `write()` function, the text itself is simply a python string.

**EDIT:**
When I modify the `write` method mentioned above like so (following @ekhumoro's suggestion):

```
def write(self, text):
    self.text_area.insertPlainText(text)
```

The text is still missing after hiding and showing the dialog.

Comment: Please provide an example. That is not the normal behavior.

Comment: You can have a minimizable modal `QDialog`. Check the `setWindowFlags` method. But that shouldn't make any text in `QPlainTextEdit` vaporize when you minimize. I suspect your window manager does something sketchy, like creating a new dialog when you minimize/restore.

Comment: @Avaris, using `setWindowFlags` like you suggest does make the window minimizeable, but the text is still missing when I restore the window.  The odd thing is that this behavior is replicable on _both_ GNOME and Xmonad.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `previous_text` contains the same overall text of the very last line in the window except that the time reflects the time when the window was brought back up ... which is strange because I'm not actually changing the time, so something else must be changing that string.  `previous_text` contains: `04/05/2012 15:12:02  root               INFO         Operations completed successfully`.

Comment: How is the string generated, and how is the text-edit updated?

Comment: @ekhumoro, The `QPlainTextEdit` contains captured standard out.  In the first image above, text such as `('------------------', u'budget_amount', u'1250.0')` is generated by various `print` statements and text such as `04/06/2012 09:49:11  warp               INFO     Finished Water Funds Prioritizer` is generated by python's `logging` module.

Comment: If you're using threads, then using `QString(text)` inside the `write` method might be problematic, because it may not be thread-safe. Try passing the python string in directly.

Comment: @ekhumoro, when I pass in the python string directly, I get the same behavior as when I cast the python string to a `QString`.